# CheckBox "checked" event is raised when I scroll down datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple datagrid and one of its columns contains a checkbox:

```xaml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked">
            <CheckBox.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding anotherColumn}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding anotherColumn}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            <CheckBox.Style>
          </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I bound that checkbox to another column using a datatrigger so it will cause the checkbox to be checked or unchecked. Accordingly, some of my checkboxes would be unchecked and some other would be checked based on the value of anotherColumn. Notice that my checkboxes have a Checked eventhandler.

The problem is, that if I scroll down the datagrid, when it reaches checkboxes that are checked, the "Checked" event will fire. This problem occurs just at the time that I scroll down the datagrid and WPF renders new checkboxes and shows them in the scene, not at the beginning of the datagrid.

To avoid this side effect I tried to use MouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown events instead of Checked event for capturing checkbox function, but the MouseLeftButtonDown event will not fire for checkbox (According to this [documnetation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(VS.100).aspx)) and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown has some side effect(for example, it would capture user's click, but checkbox won't get checked)

I like to know if there is any idea for capturing checkbox checked event in a different way or any idea that could solve the first mentioned problem that wrong events were fired.

Comment: Sounds like a non-working hack for a glitchy workaround for a not so well thought out solution to a problem you didn't even heave. (aka an XY problem). Could you describe what you are **actually** trying to do? (without describing your current code, but rather the problem you initially intended to solve).

Comment: `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `MouseDown` can be used to change checkbox state...However,before u get downvotes,please include your c# code..Then we'll be able to help u out..We are always here to hep u :)

Comment: Excuse me to introduce a rule of SO : **THE XY PROBLEM**(in short) is the stated issue of an OP where he/she hasn't described his/her wants properly...Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You know that the checked state has to be filled when control get's up to the view?  Whenever this happens the `checked` event is fired up.

Comment: All those Events/Triggers/Setters etc. are completely unneccessary. Whatever you are trying to do, is best taken care of in your ViewModel. Styles and DataTriggers are not meant as a way to modify your data, but to react to them.

Comment: Here is an example of someone who also wanted to check/uncheck checkboxes in a datagrid, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990131/3214843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Manfred said in the comments, I just need to care of my ViewModel to fix this. This unexpected behavior occurred because I was using dataTrigger for checking and unchecking Checkbox.Instead I should use viewModel to bind my checkbox to itemsource.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990131/3214843) is a good example of using checkbox in datagrid
and [here](https://www.wintellect.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained/) is a good expalnation of MVVM pattern.