# Check/Uncheck checkboxes in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

> Here are my requirements:
>
> 1. When the header check box is checked, all the checkboxes in that column will be checked.    When the header check box is unchecked, all
>      the checkboxes in that column will be unchecked.
> 2. When all checkboxes in the column are cheched, uncheck one of them will uncheck the header checkbox.    When check one by one checkboxes
>      in the column, the header checkbox will be checked.
>
> How do I achieve this?
>
> Here is my xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chbHeader" IsChecked={"Binding AllChecked"} />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chbHeader}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955781/wpf-select-all-checkbox-in-a-datagrid/48989696  This will be the exact solution you need.

Comment: I got the ItemSource updated, but the UI did not work, ie the checkboxes do not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

> I got it working.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.AllSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdSetChildCheckboxes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdSetHeaderCheckbox, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In C# code, have the properties IsChecked/AllChecked, and commands implemented accordingly.